# Does msmdpump.dll pass the authentication info to SSAS?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssas

I'm using msmdpump.dll with basic authentication to access a SSAS OLAP cube from the internet. Does this method pass the auth info to SSAS so if I put permissions on the cube they get applied depending of the user I input in my connection string? If not, is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, msmdpump will pass the authentication through to SSAS.

[Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2005/administrator/cc917711(v=technet.10)) is an article on how to get it all set up for SSAS 2005.

[Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/sqldev/how-to-configure-http-access-to-sql-server-2008-analysis-services-on-iis7) is one for IIS7 to SSAS 2008.